# Asp.NET Core unpredictable localization result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have implemented localization in my ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web API project following this documentation: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-files).

I did everything pretty much the same way as the examples show, but for the sake of completeness I will post the relevant pieces of my code here. The localization is configured this way:

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{    
  services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Strings");    
  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>    
  {
      options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
      options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("bs-Latn-BA") };
      options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
      {
         new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider()
      };    
  });    
 services.AddTransient<EmailSender>(); 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{      
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
}
```

I use the resources in the `EmailSender` class:

*EmailSender.cs*

```
public EmailSender(IStringLocalizer<EmailSender> stringLocalizer)
{
   myResource = stringLocalizer["MyResourceName"];
}
```

The `EmailSender` class is located in a Helpers folder, and my .resx file are located in the Strings folder, and named like this:

*Helpers.EmailSender.en-US.resx*

*Helpers.EmailSender.bs-Latn-BA.resx*

**The results:**

When I change the default culture manually, everything works as expected and the correct version of the resource string is always returned.

However, I want the culture to be provided by the `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider`, but when I test my app by creating requests using Postman or Swagger, the results are unpredictable.

The request is formatted like this:
*https://localhost:44386/api/v0.1/login?culture=en-US*. Changing the default culture in startup / query culture combination gives these results:

en-US / en-US -> en-US

en-US / bs-Latn-BA -> en-US (this is wrong)

bs-Latn-BA / en-US -> en-US

bs-Latn-BA / bs-Latn-BA -> bs-Latn-BA

So, changing the culture works when the bs-Latn-BA is default, but not when en-US is default.

I am really confused by this behavior, and am even considering the possibility of a bug in the localization framework.

Comment: Most likely a bug in configuration. `en-US` is the default *fallback* culture when the requested culture can't be found. The combinations you posted suggest `bs-Latn-BA` isn't working at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But I do get the bs-Latn-BA strings when that's both the default and the requested culture. Also, when bs-Latn-BA is default and I request English, English is returned which suggests that both my bs-Latn-BA resources and parsing the query string work...

Comment: In .NET (all stacks, versions) localization is controlled by a thread's UICulture and Culture properties. UICulture affects the UI and resources, Culture parsing and formatting. Try debugging `EmailSender` and check that those properties are for the thread, request. It *could* be that the string localizer chokes on three-part cultures. If you check [QueryStringRequestCultureProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d5cc8cbad9b593163764b3cbcb94ec9816acfcbe/src/Middleware/Localization/src/QueryStringRequestCultureProvider.cs) you'll see the code is pretty cut-and-dried

Comment: You could also try using a different culture string to isolate the problem. If a two-part works but a three-part fails, if the thread, request cultures are OK, you'll know the problem has to do with the resource files.

Comment: I've already tested with two-part culture and it made no difference. Also, the UICulture is set to Culture by default, so it shouldn't matter that I'm not setting it explicitly in my request.

Comment: `and it made no difference` in that case, there's something wrong with the project. If localization didn't work at all, people would have noticed. Perhaps the paths are wrong, the folder is wrong, the `resx` files weren't compiled or copied.

Comment: Try downloading and just running the sample from the [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) article. The Github repo [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/Localization).